# Version Control Vagrant and Ansible virtual box config with Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, repository, vagrant, ansible

Just setting up a new Rails app and I have my Vagrant files along with a folder full of dev machine provisioning files for Ansible. These allow me to spin up a dev virtual machine, provision it and have everything up and running really quickly.

My question is, should all that be in my projects version control repository? I will be working on this project across several machines so have it accessible and synced would be useful but on the other hand I don't wish those items to be deployed when I finally deploy it to production? Also, having those files committed would keep a history of them which would also be nice.

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a thing of your personal preference.
Some people keep everything in a single self-contained repo. Other people keep application code in a separate repo from their configuration/provisioning/deployment code.
Either way have their own benefits and drawbacks and there's no wrong of doing it as long as you do keep in some version control system.

Comment: Ok, If I do add it to my repo, is there a way to get ONLY my Rails app to be deployed to a production server?

Comment: Keep playbooks and app code in separate dirs and check out only that part.

Comment: I've been thinking more about this recently. Would git submodules work here? Have a repo for the devbox and use submodules to clone my apps repo inside that one?

Answer (score 1):

When I set up new projects I create a directory structure along the lines of:

```
/<application_name>
   ./src
   ./deployment
   ./docs
```

Actual source code goes in `src`, any deployment-specific scripts (e.g. Ansible playbook dirs, Vagrant files) go in `deployment` and of course any documentation goes in `docs`.

Then I commit all this to source control. The deployment scripts are then written to be executed from their directory but change into the `src` directory to perform their actions.